# Why isn't wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry') working?

Tags: javascript, masonry

I'm trying to add masonry sript to my site, but `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry');` is not adding the script.

Instead I have to use:

```
wp_register_script('jquery_masonry', includes_url(). '/js/jquery/jquery.masonry.min.js', 'jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery_masonry');
```

Why is that?

Comment: I took it because the answer was not helpful at all, sorry

Comment: @G.M. even if I'm not directly involved, I've tried the code as above and I can get it to work only with `wp_register_script` in `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. this issue is very interesting.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because I was not understand the question: my english is poor. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry')` works fine for me. You are certain it is not being added? You are not looking at a cached page somehow?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's Masonry is [bundled with WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress). All you should need is `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry');` but note that the "slug" is `jquery-masonry`, not `jquery_masonry`. And be sure your are enqueueing on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook or later.

```
function enqueue_masonry() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_masonry');
```

I'd guess that your problem has something to do with when you register/enqueue because loading core scripts is pretty straightforward.

If that doesn't work, something is wrong with your site. A plugin or a theme is deregistering, perhaps. Without more information it is going to be hard to say what.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers his question, which is why does `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry')` not work for him.

Comment: @vancoder wp_enqueue_script('jquery_masonry') don't work for him. s_ha_dum says: _but note that the "slug" is 'jquery-masonry', not 'jquery_masonry'_

Comment: @vancoder : see the edit. I am guessing about why it doesn't work, which is about all I can do with the information provided. Those are the only two things I can think that might go wrong, short of server level stuff.

Comment: @G.M. You mis-read the question.

Comment: @vancoder I think you mis-read the **code** in the question

Comment: @s_ha_dum I'm using the correct slug when I try using only `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry');`. But that alone is not loading the masonry js script. I have to use my other method.

Comment: @Steven : Did you see the rest of the answer? The parts about `wp_enqueue_scripts` and deregistering?

Answer (score 2):

s_ha_dum is correct, you don't need to enqueue it yourself.

That being said, the reason your script is not working is because your dependancy variable is not an array. Your code should read:

```
wp_register_script('jquery_masonry', includes_url(). '/js/jquery/jquery.masonry.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

Way down deep in the WP_Dependancies class, if the value passes is not an array, it sets it to be a blank array, therefore making it have no dependancies. (see wp_includes/class.wp_dependancies.php line 251 as of WP 3.6, if interested)

So what I assume is happening, is it's loading in the Masonry script BEFORE jQuery is loaded in, therefore causing it to do nothing.

That being said, use s_ha_dum's response, as it's already registered in WordPress, and waiting to be en-queued.